# Can Chrome extensions access other Chrome extensions' data?

Tags: password-management, chrome, browser-extensions

Can the data in a password-manager Chrome extension be accessed by a different Chrome extension? For example, if one were to install a malicious extension, could that extension access the data (i.e., the passwords) inside an extension like 1Password X? Could the malicious extension log the password a user types to unlock an extension like 1Password X, despite 1Password X not having users type on a webpage per se?

Comment: 1. depends, they could use older storage method, but new interfaces are siloed and also protected by the OS. 2. no, but it could rip it from the page once 1password inject it into the form. 3. it depends on where the user is actually typing, often it's markup injected into the page to make a "modal" (unsafe). If it's from a menu or some kind of chromeless popup, then no.